# How to communicate to a TWebModule

Tags: delphi, components, indy, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a webservice constructed as follows

Main unit (a `TForm`):

```
private
  FWebBrokerBridge: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge;

In the create:
  FWebBrokerBridge := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);    // TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge = class(TIdCustomHTTPServer), in IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas
  FWebBrokerBridge.RegisterWebModuleClass(TWebModuleWebServices);
  FWebBrokerBridge.... set some properties
  FWebBrokerBridge.DefaultPort := FPort;
  FWebBrokerBridge.Active := True;
```

The `TWebModuleWebServices` is in:

```
unit DMWebServices;

interface

type
   TWebModuleWebServices = class(TWebModule)
      procedure WebModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);

      procedure WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
        Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
      procedure WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
        Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
        
      procedure WebModuleWebServicesTTInfoAction(Sender: TObject;
        Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
      ... other actions
```

The main unit reads a boolean setting from an INI file and I want that value to be known in each `TWebModuleWebServices` instance.
But how to do that?

- The `WebModuleCreate` sender is a `TWebModuleWebServices` so I don't see much opportunity there. Maybe override the Create?
- Use the `TWebModuleWebServices` Tag property?
- Use a global variable or a singleton (it's a global boolean setting, nothing complicated)?

What would be a smart approach?

Answer (score 0):

A general purpose good (object oriented) pratice is:

1. Create a new TWebModule descendendant, and register it as a component into your own package.
2. Publish a new property to pass data you need to transfer.
3. Create you `TWebModuleWebServices` module inheriting from your new web module by the Delphi UI.
4. Use the new property to dispatch data.

Comment: Sounds like the way to go, but do I need a package and registering? Wouldn't just a subclass be enough?

Comment: Yes, you ha to subclass (as I described) the TWebWebModule and register it, then you can find it into "FIle -> New" Delphi dialog.

Comment: I don't need that last part, that's where my question came from. IIRC I don't have to register it.